# How to implement custom css in Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I could not implement customer css in Ruby on Rails application. The changes that I've made locally don't shown up on the pages in Heroku.

I find similar question and one answer on it.
Even so this answer was not marked as the solution, I’ve changed files accordingly this answer and the link provided(see below). 
Yet, I still could not implement customer css.

[Ruby on Rails Tutorial custom CSS not showing up in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48371744/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-custom-css-not-showing-up-in-app)

//edited

I find that the possible reason for not shown up css is that  precompile run locally(link below) and deleted as suggested file .json.
But the custom.css is not implemented yet.

https://help.heroku.com/TEN5TWQ1/why-are-my-css-js-changes-not-showing-up-in-my-rails-app

```
    ‘’’ Gemfile’’’
    gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.3.6'
    gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.6'
```

‘’’app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss’’’ -edited

```
@import main;
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "custom";
@import "styles";
@import 'colors';
@import "sessions";
@import "users";
```

‘’’app/assets/javascripts/application.js’’’

```
     //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs

    //= require bootstrap

//= require_tree .

    bundle install

//edited

'''application.html.erb'''

    !DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                               "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
      </head>
       <body>
        <body>
        <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
        <div class="container">
          <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
            <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
          <% end %>
          <%= yield %>
          <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
          <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>


    <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
            <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
          <% end %>



    //custom.css.scss(first lines)
    //edited


        * mixins, variables, etc. */
    .t-a
     {
    color: red;
    }


//applicatio.css.scss
//edited

    *
     * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
     * listed below.
     *
     * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,

     *= require_tree .
     *= require_self
     *= require custom.css.scss
     */

    @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
    @import "bootstrap";
    @import "custom";
    @import "styles";
```

Comment: add the link to the other question you mentioned

Comment: the link was added

Comment: Can you copy your views/layout/application.html.erb file in your question ?

Comment: the file was added.

Comment: That is strange. Your `application.html.erb` layout view imports a single file : `application.scss` which itself imports `custom.css`. Try to rename `application.scss` into `application.css.scss` to properly show preprocessors. And also copy your `custom.css` file here. Also what change from your css file is not showing ? No css files attached at all ?

Comment: But the answer (see link in my question) specifically said:
v
 "I would rename the application.css to application.scss and then get rid of the

 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self"
and I followed this.
Could you put your recommendations as the answer if your custom.css work to try it out.

Comment: I've changed to application.css.scss  but it doesn't  allow me do any formatting. This file is pretty big. Yes, no css changing at all: like it doesn't exist. I've tried to change error color, h1, h2 - no changes went through.

Comment: As for Hartl, he simultaneously uses two ways to connect files. This is the wrong approach. Perhaps he demonstrates this for educational purposes. But it confuses the novice. I indicated in my answer how to make the correct connection of stylesheet files.

Comment: I would love to know the right approach that is working:.

Comment: Maxence, it is indeed  strange...If I put some class in custom.scss or styles.scss, I could see it on page but I could not see the color that I put in. Also, if i change something in custom.css - it doesn't show on pages....When I push to Heroku I've got message: 
Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally... but get rid from this file bring me to no formatting at all(see reference in initial post).  How don't  loose formatting that I have and be able to add. something new using custom, style.scss, anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could  implement customer css in Ruby on Rails application. For example, you could change a color of the texts or the links, or the font sizes regardless of the first or the second approach(see below)

the first approach:

using import statements in  application.scss:

```
    @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
    @import "bootstrap";
    @import "custom";
    @import "styles";
```

the second approach:

```
   a) using import statements in custom.scss :
      @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
      @import "bootstrap";

   b) using statements as below in the application.scss:
         *= require_tree .
         *= require_self

You should not mix up the first and the second approach.

    You could not change hover as you would  like because
    it need to be to complied with bootstrap settings.
    For example, changing hover to green or red produces error.
    So, I ended up using the grey-darker color(see below) instead.
    You could override bootstrap but it is considered as the
    bad idea. 


    examples of changing  formatting:

        h1.green-text { color: green; font-size: 10em; }

        <h1 class="green-text">This text is very large and green
        </h1>


        a {
         color: green;
         &:hover {
             color: $gray-darker;
           }

         }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` and rename all `.css` in `.scss`.

Then in your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` delete all `*= require` and use:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "custom";
```

In your `app/assets/stylesheets/custom.scss` use just usual CSS-classes and  SCSS without any `@import`.

Be careful and don't use in both files the same classes because of overriding.

If you decide to have new file says `app/assets/stylesheets/styles.scss`.

You need to add to `application.scss`

```
@import "styles";
```

That should works perfectly.

Comment: I would like anything that show any of  my customization, like color h1, h2  and so on . I can override Bootstrap classes or not -it doesn't matter.  So, I took of "s" from customs but there is no effect at all - noting changes.

Answer (score 1):

Always follow one approach. Either

1) if you are using .scss file then use @import only.

```
  @import "custom"
```

Remove all other syntax like 
      *=require "custom"

Or 2) If you are using .css file then use only below syntax

```
  *= require "custom"
```

And remove all @import syntax

Never mix them like you did in your code.

Do one thing , follow second one approach. And require your custom css file just above the *=require_tree . For ex.

```
 *=require "custom"
 *=require_tree .
```

Then let me know. After doing this, do not forget to restart your server as these files load once at the time server start.

Comment: I've updated(see initial version) but no any changes shown.

Comment: No need to write require 'custom' in application.css file as require_tree already import all the file that is under the stylesheets folder. Anyway have you checked rails console or browser console for the errors ? Remove @import in custom.scss file, no need. Can you show the  
current application.css for both js and css file. Please edit your question for code.

Comment: the application.scss  was shown already (there are 3 line @import), the application.js was added.

Comment: Oh! Then everything looks perfect. One last option just run command..  rake assets:clobber .... After that restart the server then check it.

Comment: This cimmand 
Removed …..new/public/assets
And then 
Precompiling assets failed.
And it doesn’t changed any custom formatting and I could not push to heroku and need go back.
And even if I go back heroku still show that my branch ahead of one comment and it actually delete publ/assets dir ... that why probably this error occurred

Comment: Any idea how to bring back public/assets  because right now this command delete it? Or if it is necessary don't restore this directory but make custom.css work and get rid from precompiling error to push to heroku?

Comment: Precompiling assets failed. It shows that you have a problem with the stylesheets or JavaScript. Please check the file with online checker tools.  You cannot revert it back. I recommend to correct all the error.  And precompile the assets. Popular tools like csslint.net and jslint.com

Comment: First you wrote the require custom is needed, then that is not. What is correct? How to check for error using:
rails console
Running via Spring preloader in process 1068
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.7.2)

Comment: If you are using require_tree in application file then it is not needed. It is difficult to rectify js and css error by rails logs. sometimes it is bypass in case of developement. And moreover it doesn't show the exact error and where it is. Especially for CSS error. I have faced a lot this.

Comment: I have no errors right now when  I see source code. I've added a lot od @imprt , took off *=require as was suggested ....but still could not fully change css..... It looks like common problem with no solution yet: I've read about 10 posts with different suggestion and commands to use, try all of them...but still no ability  to change css.. Taking off the file to get rid from precompiling locally(see original post) doesn't solve issue but create completely not formatted output...Is it heroku issue and other server provider would be fine?
 Any suggestion how to make custom css to work?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Ruby expert. I will give advice based on my experience, that may differ from actual good practice.

**1st thing:** If you are writing Sass, I have realised it is good practice to show all preprocessors in the file name. The way it works is that the furthest preprocessor from file name will be interpreted first. 
For example: file `whatever.js.coffee.erb` will be first interpreted by Ruby interpreter, then by coffee script interpreter, and then final file will be some javascript.

When compiling my assets locally I have noticed I had to be explicit with names. So basically renaming `application.scss` to `application.css.scss` is harmless and good practice.

(though it may not be the source of your problem)

**2nd thing**: The bits you have provided don't really explain why `custom.css` styles are not showing in your view.

Why ?

Because your code "looks" good to me.

What is it doing ?

Well your Rails app has stylesheets located in app/assets/stylesheets. Though those stylesheets will not automagically appear on your web pages.

In order to add these stylesheets to your pages there is a helper called `stylesheet_link_tag`. `stylesheet_link_tag` will just add a link to the stylesheet file in your HTML page. It needs be placed between `<head></head>` html tags.

In Rails though you don't recreate the `<head></head>` tags for every page. All views inerhit from a global layout template called `application.html.erb` (you know about this one, you copied content) and this is the place you can ***globally*** handle stylesheets attachment.

In your tutorial, the mentor has added a single stylesheet in the `application.html.erb` file : `application` (Rails will understand it as `application.css` or `application.css.scss` ... and try to find it in the app/assets/stylesheets folder) . All the webpages of your website will have this very stylesheet.

But then you tell me : "how can I have a single file for my whole app.. I have lots of controllers and views?"

This is where it gets interesting: there are a few tricks to tweek this stylesheet. Mostly `@import` and `*= require`. Both allow to import other stylesheets into the current stylesheet. (require is Ruby, import is Sass)

```
/*
 *= require custom.css.scss 
*/
@import "custom";
```

The above code will do the same: aggregate the file `custom.css.scss` to `application.css`. If you add more files they will be aggregated too.

some specifics:

`*= require_tree.` will import every stylesheet in app/assets/stylesheets folder. Quite convenient if you want to make a very big css file that can be used on every page of your site.

`*= require_self` will process what is after the commmented part. basically it says: "disregard the styles, just do the require things"

Ok now what you can do :

- rename `application.scss` to `application.css.scss`
- reinstate `require_self` : I am not sure it actually has any effect on the @imports but it is no harm to have it.

If that does not solve your problem : 
Add the custom file in a require :

```
 /*
   *= require custom.css.scss 
 */
```

It should not fail (don't forget to rename custom as per above though)

Last think: reinstate `require tree.` It should gather all stylesheet files and aggregate them to `application.css` (here I write `application.css` because I talk about the stylesheet in the final webpage and not the file in your Rails app)(also in development your `application.css` file may not look `aggregated` but it will in production)

Comment: You wrote that you are not Ruby expert and it maybe not good practice and suggest to reinstall some code that was precisely  suggested to be deleted (the link  in the initial question) and the person  who gave this suggestion maybe an export and it is good practice.....yet it doesn't work.
I'll try your suggestion and mark as solution if it works or ask some specific question regarding.

Answer (score 0):

I saw in one answer that it was resolved by putting `@import "custom"` above `@import "boostrap"`. May be you should try that.